# Filter bar is not displaying when I use custom data for column in Yii framwork

Tags: php, yii, yii-components

I've created crud for user table. In admin page I've implemented custom code for displaying custom column values in `$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView',array())....` When I try to add code for custom data in column filter bar from that column of the table is not displaying. 
Following is my code in view of the admin page

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'users-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
    'filter'=>$model,
        'itemsCssClass' => 'table table-responsive  table-striped table-hover table-bordered',
    'columns'=>array(
        array(
                    'header' => 'ID',                                        
                    'type' => 'raw',                    
                    'value' => function($model, $key, $index) {
                        return 'HJ-'.date('Ym',  strtotime($model->created_date)).$model->id;
                    },

                ),

        array(
                    'header' => 'First Name',                                        
                    'type' => 'raw',
                    'value' => '$data->fname',
                ),
        array(
                    'header' => 'Last Name',                                        
                    'type' => 'raw',
                    'value' => '$data->lname',
                ),
                'contact_no',
         array(
            'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
        ),
    ),
)); ?>
```

In above code, filter bar is displaying for 'contact_no' but its not displaying for ID, First Name and Last name due to custom code. How to add filter bar to this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to indicate which attribute the data belongs to via [`name`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDataColumn#name-detail). From the docs:

> [name]: the attribute name of the data model. Used for column sorting, filtering and to render the corresponding attribute value in each data cell. If value is specified it will be used to rendered the data cell instead of the attribute value.

As such your code should be as follows:

```
array(
    'header' => 'First Name',                                        
    'type' => 'raw',
    'value' => '$data->fname',
    'name' => 'fname',
),
```

[Also](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CGridView#columns-detail):

> When a column is specified as a string, it should be in the format of `"name:type:header"`, where "type" and "header" are optional.

thus the above can be shortened as follows:

```
'columns'=>array(
    ...
    'fname:raw:First Name',
    'lname:raw:Last Name',
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks @topher.... Your first code worked. But only one problem that is, the code working with first name and last name but its not working with first column that is ID that I've appended some custom text such as 'HJ'.

Comment: What do you mean not working? Is the filter not showing?

Comment: filter bar is displaying but its not working because I've appended some custom text such as 'HJ-' etc.Its filtering with only id but its not filtering with appended custom text that is 'HJ-' etc

Comment: That is the expected behaviour. The default filter does its search against what is in the database and nowhere else. The text 'HJ-' etc doesn't exist in the database.